# Can not use clangd to read linux kernel code

Tags: linux-device-driver, vscode-extensions, clangd

I have some codes about Linux kernel driver. I use **bear make** to generate compile_commands.json.

this is some of my compile_commands.json:

```
"directory": "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-90-generic",
"file": "../../../home/ubuntu/programs/linuxKLearn/2/2.1/PrintingDriver/DriverFileOperations.c"
```

this is my Makefiles:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := PrintModule.o
    PrintModule-objs := DriverMain.o DriverFileOperations.o
EXTRA_CFLAGS := -DTEST_DEBUG -ggdb -O0
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    rm *.order *.symvers *.mod.c *.o .*.o.cmd .*.cmd .tmp_versions -rf
endif
```

But when I use Vscode and clangd to read them, clangd shows that there is some problems when including <linux/mm.h>, the problems are as below:

```
Unknown argument: '-mno-fp-ret-in-387'
Unknown argument: '-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3'
Unknown argument: '-mskip-rax-setup'
Unknown argument: '-mindirect-branch=thunk-extern'
Unknown argument: '-mindirect-branch-register'
......
```

And clangd cannot find ssize_t. **Unknown type name 'ssize_t'clang(unknown_typename)**
.the inode also has warning **Declaration of 'struct inode' will not be visible outside of this functionclang(-Wvisibility)**,

How to fix include <linux/mm.h> and find ssize_t?

All help is welcome, thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Kernel generate compile-commands.json for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324820/linux-kernel-generate-compile-commands-json-for-module)

Answer (score 3):

What compiler did you use to build the code? I had the same issue, and [building with Clang](https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/llvm.html) seemed to fix it. GCC and Clang have some options that are only implemented by one of the two compilers or options that are named differently, so `clangd` doesn't understand all the arguments used by GCC.

For example,

```
make CC=clang defconfig
make CC=clang
```

Or to cross compile:

```
make CC=clang ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- defconfig
make CC=clang ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

Then you can run `scripts/clang-tools/gen_compile_commands.py` to generate a `compile_commands.json`. After restarting VSCode or `clangd` and opening a C file in the project, you should see the indexing begin again, and this time there shouldn't be any errors in the output and cross-references should work when it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

Building with Clang is surely a solution, but sometimes building with GCC is necessary. Under such circumstance, [clangd's `CompileFlags` option](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#compileflags) is helpful.

This is an example configuration of .clangd, which tell the clangd to ignore the options, then warnings disappeared.

```
CompileFlags:
  Remove: [-fconserve-stack, -fno-allow-store-data-races, -mfunction-return=thunk-extern, -mindirect-branch-cs-prefix, -mindirect-branch-register, -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern, -mskip-rax-setup, -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3, -mno-fp-ret-in-387]
```